# mouse down not working: jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to trigger the below function on the mouse down event on the class yeti. However,this does not seem to work.

```
<body>
<div class="gameholder">
    <div class="title"></div>
    <div class="penguin1"></div>
    <div class="penguin2"></div>
    <div class="penguin3"></div>
    <div class="penguin4"></div>
    <div class="penguin5"></div>
    <div class="penguin6"></div>
    <div class="penguin7"></div>
    <div class="penguin8"></div>
    <div class="yeti"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {

    //This code will run after your page loads
    $('body').on('mousedown', '.yeti', function(event) {

     alert("Yaaaarrrr!");

});
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Your code works just add some text to yeti.

Comment: Atleast add something in your class `yeti`

Comment: your .yeti element is probably invisible (add a background and a size)

Comment: working fine. [check here](https://jsbin.com/vewawofivo/edit?html,js,output). Just add some text in `yeti`

Comment: Did you include jquery ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct and should work (I just tested with jQuery 2). Make sure to put something inside the yeti div or make it a fixed size (width and height).

Comment: _thanks_ for your help, now it works fine. My jquery file was misplaced

Answer (score -2):

Now it will work perfectlly..:)

```
<body>
<div class="gameholder">
    <div class="title"></div>
    <div class="penguin1"></div>
    <div class="penguin2"></div>
    <div class="penguin3"></div>
    <div class="penguin4"></div>
    <div class="penguin5"></div>
    <div class="penguin6"></div>
    <div class="penguin7"></div>
    <div class="penguin8"></div>
    <div class="yeti"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
    $(".yeti").mousedown(function(){
       alert("yeti pressed");

    });

});
});
</script>
</body>
```